# How to get the page title every time the url changes with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, events, phantomjs, casperjs

I've checked the CasperJS documentation, and it seems that there's no event that gives me access to the current document when a navigation occurs. So is it possible to get the new title of a page every time there is a navigation?

Comment: Please explain why the [navigation.requested](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#navigation-requested) event doesn't solve your problem. Are you talking about single-page-applications?

Comment: As far as I know "navigation.requested" is emmitted before the navigation has completed, so I won't have access to the navigated page title.
For example, this code won't work: http://pastie.org/10267301 . It will only output 'Navigation occurred'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[url.changed](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#url-changed) is emitted as soon as another URL is loaded which usually means that the title has also changed. It seems it isn't emitted at the end of the page load so you also need to add a step for CasperJS to wait until the page is loaded.

```
casper.on("url.changed", function(){
    this.then(function(){
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    });
});
```

You can use the [navigation.requested](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#navigation-requested) event in exactly the same way.

Comment: `casper.on("url.changed", function(){
 this.echo('Navigation occurred');
 this.echo(this.getTitle());
});`

When I use this code the only output I get is 'Navigation occurred'.

Comment: Turns out the documentation is misleading. I tried it myself and fixed the code.

Comment: Take this php file as an example: http://pastie.org/10267840 . It's original title is 'aaa', and it navigates after a second to a new page with the title 'bbb'.
When I try to handle this with "url.changed", "navigation.requested" or "resource.received" I get only the first title ("aaa"), and not the second ("bbb").

Comment: Well, the page does a redirect on its own. Do you wait for that redirect in CasperJS? If the script is finished CasperJS will exit.

Comment: How should I tell it to wait for the redirect?

Comment: If you know the time, just do a static `casper.wait(1000)`, but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an *ever-so-slightly* **faster** version of the accepted answer that will make a significant difference if you are dealing with many URL changes:

```
casper.on('url.changed', function () {
  this.then(function () {
    console.log(this.page.title);
  });
});
```